# Assembly Reference Catch-22

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-assembly

I'm trying to integrate MangoChat into an existing .Net project. Mango requires the use of Newtonsoft.Json version 3.5.0.0, however my current version of this assembly is 6.x.

Logically, I thought to uninstall the current version but it has so many dependencies that it tears apart the project. I can't install version 3.5.0.0 beside 6.x because I can't add a second assembly to the .bin folder with the same name.

How could I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If version 6.x is compatible with version 3.5.0.0, you can add a binding redirect to new version. You should add it to your configuration file:

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="[enter token here]" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="3.5.0.0-6.X" newVersion="6.X"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Replace 6.X with your actual version.

Another option is to add assembly to different folder and use AssemblyResolve event on AppDomain to find it. You can use such code:

```
//Load assembly from alternative location
Assembly newtonsoftAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\PathToYourAssembly.dll");
//Handle AssemblyResolve event
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) =>
{
    //Check if your assembly was requested
    if (args.Name.Contains("Newtonsoft.Json"))
    {
        return newtonsoftAssembly;
    }
    return null;
};
```

You should run this code once, e.g. during application startup.

Comment: Working on all of the above.

Comment: I like the web.config version, but does this assumes backward compatibility? (which I'm *guessing* this assembly has)

Comment: It does not assume or guarantee backwards compatibility. Only instead of using version 3.5 it uses version 6.0. If there were any breaking changes you'll get an error. Second option is safer, but in this case you have to keep 2 assemblies which is not very convenient

Comment: I tried making the appropriate changes in web.config and got this:: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)fig and got this:

Comment: Ok, scrap that, I got it to work. I placed your code in the Configuration(IAppBuilder app) method in startup.cs. A possible addition to your code might be the addition of a second condition in the 'if' statement:  && args.Name.Contains("Version=3.5.0.0"); That way, all other requests for Newtonsoft.Json for new versions would still resolve to that assembly. Great code, thank you.